# Hibernate relations

Tags: hibernate

I want to query child object while loading,

here is the query i am using :

```
SELECT app FROM ApplicantPerson app left join app.gpaList gpa , DesignatedSchool ds
WHERE
    app.applicantPersonId.applPersonId = ds.applPersonId 
    AND app.appStatusCd = 'P'  and gpa.verifiedInd= 1
    AND ds.designateStatusCd = 'A' 
    AND ds.medInstId = ?  
    AND app.applicantPersonId.applYear = ?
    AND ds.applYear = ?
```

but applicantperson is having 24 records, and child gpalist has 2 records with one verified = 1 and the second is having verified =0

Note: there is one to many relation between ApplicantPerson and Gpa

But the output of the above query is 30 records and gpalist is getting 2 records.

I need out put with 24 records in parent and child gpalist with one record verified =1

Answer (score 0):

The where clause is used to select *which* entities are returned by the query, but it doesn't modify *what* is returned by the query. If a query returns instances of `ApplicantPerson`, and you ask for the children of the returned persons, you'll always get all the children, whatever the query used to get those persons.

Your query performs a cartesian product between `app` and `ds`, so it's not surprising that you get more rows than you expect. Use the distinct keyword to get distinct instances:

```
select distinct app from ...
```

Comment: I tried distinct, I am getting 24 records of applicantperson, but child list GPA list 2. GPA list need to be 1 verifiedid=1

Comment: This is not possible. That's not what a query does. An entity is an entity. It always contains what is in the database, and not the result of a query.

Comment: Ok thanks, I got some alternative... @Filter in hibernate. Is this the correct way. Can you please suggest me.

Comment: I mean using http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-filters